# An experiment with truly indistinguishable dice?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A classic problem in courses on discrete probability is something like, "if you roll two fair dice, what is the probability that their sum is 6?". The solution is usually something like drawing a $6 \times 6$ grid enumerating the possibilities for what the two numbers on the dice could be, and then counting the number of pairs $(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)$ which give a sum of 6. This yields a probability of $5/36$. If you actually do an experiment with physical dice, then you can verify this number.

Now here's what I'm wondering: if dice were indistinguishable as they typically are to most observers, then there would be not $36$ outcomes to rolling a pair of dice but rather only $21$. And there would be not $5$ outcomes which give a sum of $6$, but only $3$. Naively, the probability to roll a $6$ would be $3/21 > 5/36$. The true probability (outlined above) seems to say that the two dice are distinguishable. My internal explanation of this is that if you were to say paint one of the die red and the other blue, then they certainly become distinguishable. But of course this shouldn't affect the outcome of your experiment.

So now here's my question: could you craft a real world experiment in which the probability distribution in rolling two dice was uniform on the set of $21$ outcomes for these rolls, thinking of the die as indistinguishable?

Comment: What do you mean by "a real world experiment"?  You can define whatever distribution you want on the set of 21 unordered pairs, but in the real world the probability distribution on the outcomes doesn't changed based on how you think; it is what it is.

Comment: You'd need [Bose–Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) dice :-)

Comment: @Joe I don't know that I can give an exact definition. But I think imposing a probability distribution through your pencil-and-paper (or computer) computations is not what I mean. Ideally, there is an experiment with physical objects that you can run repeatedly to get the uniform distribution on the set of 21 outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this: take two ordinary, distinguishable dice (say, one green, one yellow) and condition on the event that the green die's value is no larger than the yellow die's. (That is; a roll that does *not* satisfy this condition would be picked up and rerolled.) This would have the effect of censoring the 15 superdiagonal entries on the $6 \times 6$ grid you referenced, and the remaining 21 dice outcomes would be equally likely.

An alternate approach: first, roll a D6. Then, roll a DX, where X is the value obtained on your first die roll.

Whether either of these are meaningful -- or whether they meaningfully satisfy the spirit of your question -- is up to you.

Comment: Ooh I do like this! It has the benefit of being easily achievable with physical objects and doesn't require the person designing and performing the experiment to really understand anything about probability.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could do the following:

Roll two dice. If they both give the same value, keep them. If the values are different, then keep them with probability 1/7 and re-roll both of them with probability 6/7.

What is the probability of, say, rolling 1,1? There are two ways to get 1,1:

1. get it in the first roll (probability 1/36), or
2. roll two different values (probability 30/36), re-roll (with probability 6/7) and then roll 1,1 on the second roll (1/36).

Overall probability is 1/36 + 30/36 * 6/7 * 1/36 = 1/21. You can readily show that this holds for all possible outcomes.

Note that the experiment above treats the dice identically and indistinguishably.